# Pipeline not found (SFRAForm) for current domain (Sites-RefArch-Site) in controller SFRAForm error occurred while rendering form on storefront

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-communities, salesforce-commerce-cloud

Sir/Ma'am,

I was trying to create a form and get the values from user then displaying the data inserted in the form in salesforce B2C. While rendering it on storefront I got an error "Pipeline not found (SFRAForm) for current domain (Sites-RefArch-Site) in controller SFRAForm error occurred while rendering form on storefront".

1.The cartridge structure looks like this:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wBBI.png)

2. Error message showing on the screen:-
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcjMf.jpg)
3. Url extension after the main page url:-
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJnEq.png)
4. **Cartridge:-**
   **Controllers folder:-**
   **1.SFRAForm.Js(pic4)**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy9JJ.png)
   **2.SFRAFormResult.Js**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8fCz.png)
   **forms\defaults:-**
   **1.SFRAFormDef.xml**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIedu.png)
   **Templets:-**
   **1.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpLgF.png)
   **2.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPbvz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same problem, even if I used the official documentation for creating a form.
First, the name of the controllers should have a lowercase ".js" .
Then, if you want to execute middleware.http at line 6 in controllers, make sure that you have it in your device, otherwise it would not be executable and the code will render an error page like that.
Try to cut down "server.middleware.http" or make sure the url is the right one.